# How to configure multiple gcloud projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-cli

On my work laptop, i have gcloud configured with our prod projects. when i do `gcloud config configurations list`, I get only one row in result, which is *ACTIVE* and it's my work-project.

Now for some personal testing, I have created a separate project which is associated with my personal email id. How would i configure/connect this project with my gcloud cli?

I have tried

- `gcloud auth application-default login` which opened the browser, i signed in using personal email id. The webpage showed me `OK` and the console never changed.
- I have also tried `gcloud auth login <personal_email_id>@gmail.com` and got the same result.

So how can i connect my personal google projects to the same gcloud which is connected to my work-prod projects. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 9):

You are mixing 2 things:

- Configuration set up in your Gcloud sdk
- The project list that you have access

You can have several Gcloud config profile for easily switching from 1 configuration to another one. Use `gcloud init` to start the config. You could override the current config or define a new one. Then, you could perform `gcloud config configurations activate <config Name>` to switch between your configurations

For listing the projects of which your current user have access, use the command `gcloud projects list`

[Here](https://www.the-swamp.info/blog/configuring-gcloud-multiple-projects/) you can also find a more detailed tutorial about how to configure Google Cloud SDK for multiple projects that may be helpful to you.