# Is it possible to auto select different "gcloud" configs for different projects in multiple workspaces / folders ? Gcloud on multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, project, gcloud, workspace

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983373/how-to-configure-multiple-gcloud-projects) and this [article](https://www.the-swamp.info/blog/configuring-gcloud-multiple-projects) we get that is possible to create multiple configs for the `gcloud` SDK.

But it seems that you have to manually switch between then, by running:

```
gcloud config configurations activate <CONFIG_NAME>
```

But is there a way for each config to be automatically selected whenever I open up a project workspace/folder on VSCode? How can I do this?

I've just tested activating a new config on a different VSCode project. That seems to update it globally. Now, all of my VSCode windows (different projects) are seeing the same activated config.

---

Isn't it dangerous? I mean, I could be uploading stuff to the cloud on a different project that I'm not aware of. How do people usually handle this? Do I need to run the `activate` command on every script before deploying something?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I am not aware of such a possibility, however I have found something interesting that may help you. There is following extension:

[GCP Project Switcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pentium10.vscode-gcp-project-switcher)

The extension only allows you to change projects, however as I looked into the [code](https://github.com/pentium10/vscode-gcp-project-switcher/blob/master/src/extension.ts#L181) it is running `gcloud set config project` command under the hood. You could raise a request to add the possibility to change the whole configuration to the instead of project only, as it is a very similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

The current gcloud [documentation discusses such ways](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/configurations#automating_configuration_switching):

> To help make changing configurations seamless, you can leverage tools such as direnv and ondir to automatically switch between configurations when you switch working directories. One way to accomplish this is to set the necessary environment variables (like CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME) in the .envrc file in the root directory of your project.

---

I personally do contract work and personal projects on the same machine, so I set it up this way:

- Creat two separate gcloud configs
- Create two separate folders to hold the contract work repos and my personal ones
- Install direnv

```
brew install direnv
```

- Create `.envrc` files in both, add the env var to them with the matching config name, and allow `direnv` to use them:

```
touch .envrc
echo "export CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=<config-name>" >> .envrc
direnv allow
```

- If done correctly, you will see something like this, when changing between these folders in the terminal:

```
direnv: loading path/to/the/.envrc
direnv: export +CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME
```

Verify active config with:

```
gcloud config list
```